# Using the faster output from 2 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, completable-future

I want to work with two threads in my Java program for a tiny part. I need to give the first call to a database and the second call to an API, both calls with same input, and then work with the output of whichever thread finishes first.

It's my first time programming with threads and I'm very confused. I've seen tutorials and they mainly explain how to get two separate things done with threads so I'm a little lost.

Can someone please help or re-direct me to any useful link they may have?

So far, as I understand it, should it look something like this? :

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(func1());
Thread thread2 = new Thread(func2());
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

But then how do I extract the output of the functions? How would I know which one has finished first?

-----------UPDATE 1---------

After trying CompletableFuture (thanks for the help Johan!) I have something like this:

```
CompletableFuture<Object> getData = CompletableFuture.anyOf(
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> getDataFromDB(clientData)),
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> getDataFromApi(clientData))
    );

    getData.thenApply(dataObject -> {
        // Cast the returned Object to the actual type of your data,
        // assuming both getDataFromDb and getDataFromApi 
        // return the same result type
        Object data = (String) dataObject;

        // Work with the returned data.
        result = (String) data;
    });
```

But I get this error for getData.thenApply():

*The method thenApply(Function) in the type CompletableFuture is not applicable for the arguments (( dataObject) -> {})*

Since I know that getData in of type String, would it be okay to just convert it to String and store the result?

Comment: Have you heard of `Callables`? It's like a `Runnable` but it can return a value.

Comment: Did you consider using [RxJava](http://reactivex.io/)? It this is just your first approach to multithreading it can be a bit overkill but it has nice operator to deal with this kind of situations

Comment: @Tavo Thanks! I looked into that too and tried it but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Pelocho That seems very fancy for such a tiny thing. The main reason I'm doing this is to give the faster output to consumers. Thanks tho!

Comment: In case you want to move to Rx you will need the [amb operator](http://rxmarbles.com/#amb). If not I've just posted a solution with `CompletableFuture` that works for me

Comment: @Pelocho Thank you so much! Your posted solution worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Johan Hirsch suggests try with `CompletableFuture`. I've just try this and it works:

```
    CompletableFuture.anyOf(
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getDataFromDB(clientData)),
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getDataFromApi(clientData)))
            .thenApply(item -> (String) item)
            .thenAccept(result -> {
                // Consume the data
                System.out.println(result);
            });
```

Beware that I'm currently **consuming** the data so it doesn't return anything. If you just want to pass the result to another `CompletableFuture` change the `thenAccept` method for a `thenApply`

Answer (score 1):

**Java 8** provides a very nice [utility class called `CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), which can help in your case.

Create two `CompletableFuture`, one for each of your tasks, and then use the `CompletableFuture.anyOf` method to wait for either one to finish.

```
CompletableFuture<TData> getData = CompletableFuture.anyOf(
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> getDataFromDb()),
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> getDataFromApi())
);

getData.thenApply(dataObject -> {
    // Cast the returned Object to the actual type of your data,
    // assuming both getDataFromDb and getDataFromApi 
    // return the same result type
    TData data = (TData)dataObject;

    // Work with the returned data.
    processData(data);
});
```

Comment: I tried that but I get an error on getData.thenApply() :

_"The method thenApply(Function<? super Object,? extends U>) in the type CompletableFuture<Object> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> dataObject) -> {})"_

My data is all in Strings but it wouldn't let me set TData as String... Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExecutorService.invokeAny](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny-java.util.Collection-)

Executes the given tasks, returning the result of one that has completed successfully (i.e., without throwing an exception), if any do. Upon normal or exceptional return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled. The results of this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while this operation is in progress.

Comment: Thank you! I looked into it though but can't seem to get the correct parameters.